# Use of AVG function to determine percentages in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know what percentage of records have a given value, where percentage is defined as the number of records that match the value divided by the total number of records. i.e. if there are 100 records, of which 10 have a null value for student_id and 20 have a value of 999999, then the percentage_999999 should be 20%. Can I use the AVG function to determine this?

Option 1:

```
SELECT year, college_name, 
       sum(case when student_id IN ('999999999') then 1 else 0 end) as count_id_999999999,
       count_id_999999999/total_id as percent_id_999999999,
       sum(case when student_id IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as count_id_NULL,
       count_id_NULL/total_id  as percent_id_NULL
       count(*) as total_id
FROM  enrolment_data ed
GROUP BY year, college_name
ORDER BY year, college_name;
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT year, college_name, 
       sum(case when student_id IN ('999999999') then 1 else 0 end) as count_id_999999999,
       avg(case when student_id IN ('999999999') then 1.0 else 0 end) as percent_id_999999999,
       sum(case when student_id IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as count_id_NULL,
       avg(case when student_id IS NULL then 1.0 else 0 end) as percent_id_NULL
       count(*) as total_id
FROM  enrolment_data ed
GROUP BY year, college_name
ORDER BY year, college_name;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Oracle. I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: The Option1 won't work because you can't refer column aliases in the same select list. The Option2 is OK except a comma after "percent_id_NULL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a similar table with 100 records, 20 999999999s, 10 nulls, and 70 1s. This worked for me on SQL Server:

```
select count(*), StudentID 
from ScratchTbl 
group by StudentID;

(No column name)    StudentID
10                  NULL
70                  1
20                  999999999

select avg(case when StudentID = '999999999' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as 'pct_9s', 
       sum(case when StudentID = '999999999' then 1 else 0 end) as 'count_9s',
       avg(case when StudentID is null then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as 'pct_null', 
       sum(case when StudentID is null then 1 else 0 end) as 'count_null'
from ScratchTbl

pct_9s      count_9s    pct_null    count_null
0.200000    20          0.100000    10
```

I have a feeling that your use of the group by clause could be creating problems for you, perhaps select a specific year/college using the where clause (and get rid of the group by line) and see if you get the results you expect.